# The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

On a Mac I have Net Core installed:

```
.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I am able to run Net Core 5.0 projects but when I try to run a NET Core 3.1 project I get:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
```

Do I need to install SKD 3.1 to?

Comment: You either need to install it, or the app needs to be self-contained

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you need to install [ASP.NET Core 3.1 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

Comment: i have download ASP.Net Core 3.1 SDK from above link and install in Mac but its not showing after running the "dotnet  --info" command on terminal